# Spark submitted application not shown in YARN web ui

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn, spark-submit

I have node where I have installed spark in yarn mode. When I run an application with

```
sudo ./usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client MySparkCode.py
```

it runs fine.

When I connect in spark history server at http://localhost:18089/ I can see my submitted application.

But When I go at Yarn recourse manager web ui at http://localhost:8088/cluster/apps my application is not showing at all. Did I do something wrong? Shouldn't my application be shown there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo ./usr/bin/spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster MySparkCode.py
```

**Try mode Cluster**